# Does the sevlet-name dispatcher point to dispatcher-servlet.xml

Tags: spring, servlets, intellij-idea

I'm totally new with `Spring MVC` and `Servlets` so I'm trying to inspect and understand the purpose of every tag and syntax it has as well as the configuration with `dispatcher.xml` and `web.xml`.

I'm using **Intellij IDEA** IDE right now.

When I created the project, I used the **IntelliJ IDEA**'s option to add Frameworks which generates the `dispatcher-servlet.xml`, `web.xml`, and `applicationContext.xml` inside the `WEB-INF` folder which was also generated by the IDE.

I understand though that there are required configurations for `Spring MVC`.

When I inspected the folders and files contained I didn't see a `.java` files yet since the project was just created. In my understanding, a servlet is a `.java` file that uses the following classes.

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
```

So, which file does `<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>` points to?

[image]

Is "`dispatcher`" just a default name? I get an error when I try to change it.

Does it point to the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file under WEB-INF folder?
Is `-servlet` considered a suffix?

This may be just a simple question but for me configuration is one of the most important things to understand.

I'd appreciate any explanation to this.

Thank you.

Comment: How about a read of [the official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-servlet).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the reference. I just started studying it by watching some video tutorial course. I'll make use of the docs link you provided. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Dispatcher points to spring [DispatcherServlet](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet) which acts as front end controller for all request are routed through. On your configuration it is mapped to any request url ending with .form, ex. http://localhost:8080/galleryframesph/gallery/index.form

by convention **dispatcher-servlet.xml** will be looked in, since it has suffix  -servlet ( as you have guessed it) ( **serletname-servlet.xml** ), this should contain your WebApplicationContext relevant beans such resolvers, handlers etc.  And typically you will applicationContext.xml imported here ( to dispatcher-servlet.xml ) where it shall contains controllers, service or repository beans

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I kind of getting it. I'm also reading the docs now. So I understand the dispatcher servlet's main purpose is to delegate a request to a controller for a specific <url-pattern> something here </url-pattern> :)